# Touch handling not responding after NSTimer invalidate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer, touchesbegan

I am creating a repeating NSTimer object that calls the `-Loop()` method every iteration of the run loop:-

```
NSTimer *loopTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIMER_INTERVAL target:self selector:@selector(Loop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Within Loop() I am invalidating the timer when it becomes necessary:-

```
[loopTimer invalidate];
```

However, after using -invalidate(), the Touch handling methods -touchesBegan(), -touchesEnded() stop responding to touch events. Does NSTimer affect the run loop to somehow?

Comment: What else is happening inside your timer method?

Comment: There is a whole lot of code. It seems that calling -invalidate() results in losing the reference to the view. I get this message when i reference the view after calling -invalidate() `[viewController view]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4b6a890`

Answer (score 1):

what else you are using in loop method...

I am not sure what problem exactly you have.Anyway try this...
You can use schedular method..

```
[self schedule:@selector(loop) interval:TIMER_INTERVAL];
```

If you unscheduling with in the same function,you can use

```
[self unschedule:_cmd];
```

otherwise,
You can use `[self unschedule:@selector(loop)];`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you didn't correctly retain the view or have released it once too often. A NSTimer retains its target object, and once you `invalidate` a timer it releases its target object. In your case, that seems to make the retain counter drop to 0 and it thus gets deallocated.

You can verify this by adding a NSLog right in front of your `[loopTimer invalidate];` and another one at the start of your view's `dealloc`. My bet is that you will see `dealloc`'s log message immediately after your `invalidate` log.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't affect your runloop in anyway. Infact I checked it myself, after i invalidated the timer i was able to process touches on screen.So i guess problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed the problem by putting -invalidate() inside the -dealloc() method. So when i want end the loop i call [self.view removeFromSuperView] and this calls invalidate eventually.

Putting -invalidate() inside view lifecyle seems to deallocate the view...